# Is there a way to use axdt with eclim?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, vim, eclim

I've got Eclipse 3.6 + eclim set up and working for PHP and JavaScript.

As I'm slowly moving away from the Flash IDE for my actionscript projects I've sucessfully installed the — limited but working — axdt plugin for Eclipse but eclim doesn't seem to work for actionscript files.

Neither FDT nor Flash Builder nor asdt/axdt being listed anywhere on eclim's site I think as3 is not supported by eclim. Am I Right?

As of now, vrapper is helping me a lot, but is there a workaround — other than buying Flash Builder/FDT/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate — to this situation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are a Linux user, otherwise you would surely know about FlashDevelop (it's experimental now, but you should be able, to an extent, to run it through Wine, too...).

Other than that, I used [this](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/) for some time and it was OK for what I needed. It has some problems on top of some problems the original has, some features entirely removed, but it's still better then AXDT.

Here are some other suggestions about AS3 editor on Linux: http://flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3973 . Unfortunately, they are not as good as commercial solutions for Win / Mac.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I almost forgot about this question. I remember looking at that thread on the FD forum some months ago… it was a good start and I think that's were I heard about fb4linux which I've been using since then without any issue. It even works with the recent Indigo update of Eclipse. Still there is no plan that I know of to support Flash Builder in Eclim.